# Is there a way to pre- & un-leak a value?

Tags: memory-leaks, rust

I'm currently looking into [doing more stuff with arrays](https://github.com/fizyk20/generic-array/pull/12), but I think the performance of those operations could be even better if we were allowed to somehow transmute into a `Leaked<T>` the array up front, only to un-leak it when the function ends. This would let us use leak amplification without a) introducing unsafety and b) setting up a `catch_panic(_)`. Is this somehow possible in Rust?

For example, creating a generic array from an iterator (this obviously does not work):

```
#[inline]
fn map_inner<I, S, F, T, N>(list: I, f: F) -> GenericArray<T, N>
where I: IntoIterator<Item=S>, F: Fn(&S) -> T, N: ArrayLength<T> {
     unsafe {
        // pre-leak the whole array, it's uninitialized anyway
        let mut res : GenericArray<Leaked<T>, N> = std::mem::uninitialized();
        let i = list.into_iter();
        for r in res.iter_mut() {
            // this could panic anytime
            std::ptr::write(r, Leaked::new(f(i.next().unwrap())))
        }
        // transmuting un-leaks the array
        std::mem::transmute::<GenericArray<Leaked<T>, N>,
                              GenericArray<T, N>>(res)
    }
}
```

I should note that if we either had compile-time access to the size of `T` or a type that can hide its innards from borrowck (like `Leaked<T>` in the example), this is perfectly feasible.

Comment: What are the performance improving that you are expecting? Not incrementing `len`?

Comment: If I try to prevent leaking by catching panics (which only works on beta/nightly anyway for now), I get about 45% more throughput than collecting into a `Vec`. I presume I can get even better results by pre-leaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using [nodrop](https://crates.io/crates/nodrop), but it could leak.

```
fn map_inner<I, S, F, T, N>(list: I, f: F) -> GenericArray<T, N>
where I: IntoIterator<Item=S>, F: Fn(&S) -> T, N: ArrayLength<T> {
     unsafe {
        // pre-leak the whole array, it's uninitialized anyway
        let mut res : NoDrop<GenericArray<T, N>> = NoDrop::new(std::mem::uninitialized());
        let i = list.into_iter();
        for r in res.iter_mut() {
            // this could panic anytime
            std::ptr::write(r, f(i.next().unwrap()))
        }
        res.into_inner()
    }
}
```

Let's suppose that after the first item (`a`) is consumed from `i` and written to `r`, a panic happens. The remaining items from `i` would be drop, but the item `a` would not. Although leaking memory [is not](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1066) considered unsafe, it is not desirable.

I think that the approach described in the question link is the way to go. It is similar to the [Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/collections/up/src/libcollections/vec.rs.html#702) and [ArrayVec](https://github.com/bluss/arrayvec/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L145) implementations. I'm using a similar approach in array library that I'm writing.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @llogiq If interest you, I wrote some code to answer other question that makes this kind of construct do not leak. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925673/how-can-i-initialize-an-array-using-a-function

Comment: Thanks again – that's mostly equal to what I came up with. My benchmarks are very promising, too – very near to plain array construction.