# Initialize array with consecutive integers

Tags: rust

What is the simplest form of initializing an array with consecutive integers from 0 to N?

I have this code, but I think idiomatic Rust will look much simpler:

```
const NUM: u32 = 8;

fn main() {
    let mut int_list: [u32; NUM as usize] = [0; NUM as usize];
    for i in 0..NUM {
        int_list[i as usize] = i;
    }
    println!("data: {:?}", int_list);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66583b8556d5eb4a624d2fff9f16ea80)

Comment: One of the duplicates [applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=60b3e25ec0b0152f089aad42d456752e).

Comment: @Shepmaster `arrayvec` is not part of main Rust source tree, so I don't want to use unofficial crates.

Comment: *I don't want to use unofficial crates* — you are going to experience a lot of problems if you choose to keep this stance. Things that many people consider "core functionality" (like random number generation) are not part of the standard library.

Comment: *Maybe someone would suggest to write a macro* — yes, they [already did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926695/155423).

Comment: Your original question has no restriction about only using the standard library, but [I'd write it basically like your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=76eea11f5d17cccad9a65077bcb9f737).

Comment: See also [Is there a way to count with macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33751796/155423).

Comment: Your question is totally answered by the duplicates, why should it be close as duplicates ?

Comment: `let int_list: Vec<i32> = (0..N).collect();`